# Can I force all my sub-sites which are created using a site template to share the same workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, administration, site-template

I am working on a sharepoint enterprise server 2013. and i have a team site collection, with the following business case:-

1. Currently the site collection contain 10 sub-sites.
2. All these sub-sites are being created based on a site template which i have created (i create a base sub-site and save it as a template).
3. Each sub site have 4 tracking lists.
4. Each tracking list is based on a separate site content type.
5. Each tracking list have a list workflow assign to it.
6. I created the list workflow using SharePoint designer 2013 , based on workflow 2010.

**The disadvantage in my case is:-**

If I want to update a certain list workflow, such as adding a new action for sending email, then i have to go to the site template & to the 10++ sub-sites and manually update the related list workflows.

**Now can I achieve this, inside SharepPoint:-**

1. Can I create 4 reusable workflows at the root site; one workflow for each list(since i have 4 lists inside my site template).
2. Publish the reusable workflows as global workflows
3. Then somehow link each global workflow with its related list inside my site template.
4. After that when i create a new sub-site based on the template, the 4 tracking lists will mainly reference the global workflow, and not its own list workflow.
5. in this case if i want to add a new action inside my workflow,, i will simple update the global workflow and have the effect on all the underlying sub-sites??

so is this scenario supported in SharePoint?

Comment: You can create the workflow and attach it to a content type, and use it in all subsites. What issue are you having exactly?

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli i have read that associating a workflow with a content type is not supported in 2013 as it was the case in sharepoint 2010?

Comment: It is supported, that's how reusable workflows work. Check this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33157.sharepoint-2013-create-reusable-workflow-on-content-type-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating reusable workflow on your content type.

For a general idea, check this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33157.sharepoint-2013-create-reusable-workflow-on-content-type-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx

For SP 2013 workflows, you might need to check this:

https://blog.lekman.com/2015/02/creating-sharepoint-designer-reusable.html

Comment: thanks for the info... so i can create a reusable workflow 2010 inside SP-2013.. and chose the related site content type.. so in this case i will have a reusable workflow linked to my site content type , and i can chose to update all the list content types to have the new workflow.. till now it is fine... but seems if i want to make my reusable workflow available to other sites within the site collection i need to publish the reusable workflow as global workflow is this correct ? as seems i can not reference a reusable workflow outside the current site unless the publish it as global.

Comment: That is correct, and you can make the workflow in 2010 mode while you're in 2013.

Comment: so is using a global workflow 2010 in sharepoint 2013 and associate the workflow with a content type, considered a valid appraoch ??or it is considered a deprecated appraoch since the new workflow2013 does not allow associating a workflow to the content type..?

Comment: Nope, it's not deprecated. You can still do that and it's supported.

Comment: will test this option and if work will update you thanks